# Macro to activate cell whose address is referenced elsewhere

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I have an array of Months and Years (formatted Jan-16, Mar-17, etc) in a single row. I have a formula that will find the current month (based on the month and year I select in a drop-down menu) and spit out the address of that given month and year:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(E3:BL3,MATCH(D1,E3:BL3,0))).
```

Works like a charm. Now I need to know how I can program a macro to look at the cell that contains the address and activate the cell whose address I am referencing.

So, for example, if the address that it spits out is Z3, the macro will then go and activate cell Z3. It needs to be dynamic because every month I will be referencing a new month and thus a new cell.

Comment: What did you try. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your drop down is linked to cell `A1` then you can fire an event on a change on that cell that will move focus to cell address indicated in your formula (I'm assuming here `B1`). You would place on the `Workbook_SheetChange` event the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Dim rngAddress As Range
        Set rngAddress = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1") 'Location of your address formula
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(rngAddress.Value2).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by placing the code on the "Workbook_SheetChange" event (I'm not super familiar with vba)? I usually add a macro and write the code in the module box. Is this not the same thing?

Comment: I suppose I should explain the full scope of what I want to accomplish:

It is a spreadsheet that projects out results by month. Each month I update the model for actuals. 

I have the formula that spits out the address on the summary page and then I need to highlight the entire column in which the referenced cell resides. The entire column will be copied and pasted over to the right. This same sequence will repeat in multiple tabs (the same column in each tab, though)

Comment: Your further indications seem somewhat outside the scope of your original questions. Based on the question as originally posted and your first comment/question... if you open the VBA window (Alt + F11), on the explorer panel go to the VBA project that represents your document. Under Microsoft Excel Objects you will double click the "ThisWorkbook" object. This will open a page where you can paste the code provided. Hope this helps.

Comment: The code worked beautifully. Is there any adjustment I can make to it to have it activate the same cell reference on every tab? Or am I dreaming?

Comment: Well you can't activate every tab at the same time. You can't select a cell for a tab that is not activated so you have to activate each. You can have a loop that cycles through all your tabs and sets the focus. Search how to loop through worksheets and place the `.Select` command inside the loop varying the Sheet it is referencing. Regards,

Comment: Also if you found my answer useful as per your original question please consider marking it as such. Cheap internet points and all ;p