# Macro to copy whatever is currently in a cell, not a hard-coded reference

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I would like the macro to copy the cell address listed in a designated cell and copy it into a "go to" box to activate that cell.

I tried recording this macro but instead of copying and pasting whatever is in the designated cell it hard-codes the cell address. This cell address will change periodically so I need it to be more dynamic.

Here is the code:

```
Range("D52").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto Reference:="R3C33"
```

Instead of the hard-coded reference (R3C33) I want whatever is currently in D52. Further, if D52 is located in a separate sheet that is not currently activated how would I need to let the macro know to pull it from D52 from a different tab?

Comment: This is why people need to stop posting [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085484/macro-to-activate-cell-whose-address-is-referenced-elsewhere#38085484) to new users.

Comment: @findwindow Keeping em honest but they have to start somewhere ;)

Comment: @MatthewD you're alive ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If **D52** contains a cell address then:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Range(Range("D52").Text).Select
End Sub
```

will go there.

For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If **D52** contains something like:

[image]

This this will first get to the proper worksheet and then to the proper cell:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String

    s = Range("D52").Text
    Range(s).Parent.Activate
    Range(s).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
Application.Goto Reference:=Range(Range("D52").Value)
```